# core data fetching the information in the array objective-c

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm quite new to Objective-C.  I've been trying to fetch from my core data entity. The following code fetches the right row because it only returns 1 result.
but when I try to `NSlog()` it to see its values what I get is:

```
iGym[3922:c07] (
    "<User: 0x8397690> (entity: User; id: 0x8341580 <x-coredata://114815EF-85F4-411F-925B-8479E1A94770/User/p19> ; data: <fault>)"
)
```

I am used to PHP that I just do a `var_dump()` and i get all the information in the array... specially when I am expecting 16 results as this entity has 16 fields.

Could anyone tell me how could I inspect that array?
and also, most important, how do I ultimately do this: fetch the `Gender` field of the matched `email` field and assign it to a `NSString` variable.

The query i want to do in sql is `SELECT Gender FROM myTable WHERE email = "something@something.com;`

```
-(NSInteger*)selectedGenderMethod
{
    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"User" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entityDesc];

    request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"email = %@",_currentUser];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSArray *matches = [[context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    NSString * someVar= [matches[0] objectForKey:@"email"];
    NSLog(@"%@",someVar);
//More to come once this is sorted
    return 0;
}
```

This fetching code is happening in my `genderPickerViewController : UIViewController`

```
NSLog(@"%@", matches[0]);
```

returns

```
<User: 0x83a6b00> (entity: User; id: 0x83995f0 <x-coredata://114815EF-85F4-411F-925B-8479E1A94770/User/p19> ; data: <fault>)
```

This is my `User.h`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface User : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * dob;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * email;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * firstTime;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * gender;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * height;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * idFB;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * idUserExternal;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * idUserInternal;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * isPT;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * language;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * metricSystem;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * nickname;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * password;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * surname;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * weight;

@end
```

`User.m`:

```
@implementation User

@dynamic dob;
@dynamic email;
@dynamic firstTime;
@dynamic gender;
@dynamic height;
@dynamic idFB;
@dynamic idUserExternal;
@dynamic idUserInternal;
@dynamic isPT;
@dynamic language;
@dynamic metricSystem;
@dynamic name;
@dynamic nickname;
@dynamic password;
@dynamic surname;
@dynamic weight;

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the user object a `NSDictionary` or an `NSArray` by chance? If that is the case you are simply logging out the object, you will need to specify a specific entity in the object to output.

For example if it's a `NSDictionary`

```
NSString *name = [matches[0] objectForKey:@"name"];
NSLog("Name %@", name);
```

You could also try

```
NSString *email = (User *)matches[0].email;
NSLog("Email %@", email);
```

Comment: The matches is a NSArray. i tried  that as NSString * someVar= [matches[0] objectForKey:@"email"];
    NSLog(@"%@",someVar); and crashed my app

Comment: Try NSLog(@"%@", matches[0]);  and see what you get.

Comment: it returns <User: 0x83a6b00> (entity: User; id: 0x83995f0 <x-coredata://114815EF-85F4-411F-925B-8479E1A94770/User/p19> ; data: <fault>)

Comment: NSManagedObjectContext *context; you mean??

Comment: Nope an object that you map your results too. Look at your xcdatamodel and look at your entities, xcode might have created it for you or you might have extended it. It appears it should be "User" for you

Comment: The User.h/m?? I posted it just now

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is right, you usually get the full objects and not only one attribute, Core Data is an object storage.

So you only need `[((User *)matches[0]) gender]` to get the gender of the returned user.
If you want to get some extra information from objects you must implement:

```
- (NSString *)description
```

It is used for converting to string and logging.

Comment: What do you mean by doing [User Gender] as it currently stands. That fetching code is in my view controller (yes, probably not the best way but its my first app). I was hoping i can get it with somehow inspecting the matches variable result.

Comment: Sorry forgot to tell you about the casting. The NSArray is an array of the managed objects so you only need to cast and use them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code,

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"email CONTAINS[c] %@", _currentUser];
```

OR

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"email CONTAINS[cd] %@", _currentUser];
```

then you can print the fetched results as type `po OBJECT_NAME.PROPERTY` in debug area